Method with optional parameters validates fine in the Editor but (sometimes) fails during compilation
I have a problem when compiling this line of code:
var span = m_tracer.StartActiveSpan("FileTrace");

What's strange about this is, this exact same line of code compiles just fine in other projects in other solutions. (In fact, it is the EXACT same line of code because the source file which contains this code is linked between several different projects in different solutions.)
The build error, which only appears in the output, is:
error CS1501: No overload for method 'StartActiveSpan' takes 1 arguments

Here's the error list; no errors!

Now here's what's strange about that method call. It is true that at the binary level, there is no overload for that method which takes 1 argument. However, all arguments except the first argument are optional so at the source level this is a valid method call!

In fact, if I remove that single parameter, IntelliSense flags the syntax as invalid.

If I put the parameter back, it removes the red squiggle. So basically the Editor is happy with the syntax, but something is going awry during the compilation step. (Although as mentioned above, this line of code compiles just fine in other project and solution contexts.)
Has anyone ever seen this and resolved this to its root cause? Thanks for your advice!
EDIT: So I'm looking at this closer and I don't understand how this ever works. Here are the two method signatures:
public TelemetrySpan StartActiveSpan(
    string name,
    SpanKind kind,
    in TelemetrySpan? parentSpan, // <- TODO: Clean this up if we ever do a major release w/ breaking changes. The "in" here was probably a copy/paste mistake. Removing would be source compatible but binary breaking.
    SpanAttributes? initialAttributes = null,
    IEnumerable<Link>? links = null,
    DateTimeOffset startTime = default)

public TelemetrySpan StartActiveSpan(
    string name,
    SpanKind kind = SpanKind.Internal,
    in SpanContext parentContext = default,
    SpanAttributes? initialAttributes = null,
    IEnumerable<Link>? links = null,
    DateTimeOffset startTime = default)

There is no type distinction between the set of required parameters! So for the following statement -
var span = m_tracer.StartActiveSpan("FileTrace");

how is the compiler to know whether to supply a TelemetryScan object or a SpanContext object? So the compiler seems correct in flagging this as an ambiguous method call. In fact, at this point, I'm more amazed at the dozen or so projects in which this compiles correctly, than at the one project in which it doesn't.

Personally, I'd ditch the shim and use Activity directly instead.

Can you elaborate on that? I'm new to this. I'm just following the code samples I've seen. Are you saying I should be using Span at all? Can you point me to a code sample? Thanks!

Take a look at the getting started guide from the OpenTelemetry website. It uses Activity (which is a span) instead, as its built into .net.

Thank you! I ditched the Tracer shim in favor of ActivitySource from System.Diagnostics. Problem solved.
