Why is the compiler flagging my use of the keyword in for a passed parameter? (C# v9.0)
Here is my method call:
   var span = m_tracer.StartActiveSpan("FileTrace", SpanKind.Internal, in parentContext, null, null, startTime);

The method signature is defined as such:
public TelemetrySpan StartActiveSpan(
    string name,
    SpanKind kind = SpanKind.Internal,
    in SpanContext parentContext = default,
    SpanAttributes? initialAttributes = null,
    IEnumerable<Link>? links = null,
    DateTimeOffset startTime = default)

As you can see, the third parameter is decorated with the in qualifier. I must comply. The editor doesn't complain -

But when I compile, here's the result:

I threw the #error version in there so you can see what version of the compiler I am using. v9.0. (I also get the same error for v7.3.) Since the in keyword was introduced with C# v7.2 I am at a loss to understand this compiler error. Thanks for any advice which you can provide.

in parameter modifier

The in modifier is required in the method declaration but unnecessary at the call site.

You just need to remove the "in" at that line.
var span = m_tracer.StartActiveSpan("FileTrace", SpanKind.Internal, parentContext, null, null, startTime);


But if I remove the in keyword I get this error: error CS1620: Argument 3 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword. OK, I'll play. I supply the ref keyword and now this is what I get: CS9194 Argument 3 may not be passed with the 'ref' keyword in language version 7.3. To pass 'ref' arguments to 'in' parameters, upgrade to language version 12.0 or greater. Do I really have to upgrade my C# version across scores of projects for one line of code?

Parameters passed through the in modifier are implicitly pass-by-reference, unless there is an overload method without the in modifier. But you may consider upgrading the visual studio.

You can see the signature definitions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78526004/method-with-optional-parameters-validates-fine-in-the-editor-but-sometimes-fai. It's a complete mess! There's a comment on that parameter: The "in" here was probably a copy/paste mistake. Removing would be source compatible but binary breaking. The other comment refers to the fact that overloaded signatures with optional parameters can cause problems. A little more diligence in code quality and we wouldn't need these comments... Right now, I have no solution for this.

Both method signatures implement the in keyword, but the parameters are different types. The way the two signatures are defined is non-standard, they shouldn't be differentiating between the overloads with optional parameters. I have no idea what this does at the binary level specifically, but obviously there is some chaos down at that level. It's curious that this compiles in dozens of other projects, but in this one project it fails.

I am a little confused, after you remove the in keyword at the call site, does this compilation error still exist?

After I remove "in" the compiler complains that the parameter needs "ref" (CS1620), but when I add "ref" the compiler complains that in order to use "ref" I need to upgrade the compiler version from v7.3 to v12.0 (CS9194).

Can it be successfully built? From your description, it seems that the methods seen by intellisense and building compiler are different. I have reviewed the code of OpenTelemetry and the in modifier has never been changed, so I suspect that you defined another version of compiler in your project (e.g. specify the CscToolPath variable).

I have 4 solutions which are referencing this code. Three of them build successfully, with the syntax StartActiveSpan("FileTrace"), relying on optional parameters, but the fourth does not. I am at a loss to explain why the fourth solution is not able to generate the method call with the optional parameters. The whole issue of passing the third parameter, the "in" parameter only comes into play because the compiler, for this fourth solution, will not accept the simple method call syntax which is working just fine for the other three solutions.
